# elastic search: How to retrieve the indexed data

Tags: import, elasticsearch

In elastic search java api, suppose I am building the indexed data using this client

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("es").node();
Client client = node.client();

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                .endObject()
              )
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

This indexed data is stored in folder XYZ/elasticsearch/data.
My question is how to retrieve this indexed data in java from some other client or some other code. Is there any way in which I can give the path and the already indexed data can be imported, then I can perform queries on it?

Edit :

The code for client on other computer

```
    Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("es").node();
Client client = node.client();

MatchQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("user", "kimchy");
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch("twitter").setTypes("tweet");
SearchResponse big = srb.setQuery(qb).execute().actionGet();
SearchHit[] results = big.getHits().getHits();
```

This shows

```
  search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed
```

Thanks

Arya

Comment: why are you not querying it directly on http://localhost:9200 
you can get started with a match_all query

{ "query" : {"match_all":{}}

Comment: @AkashYadav , thas the thing, I will not be querying on my computer, I will be just indexing it, then I will be just transferring the folder containing data to some other computer, where I will be querying it, How can I retrieve this already indexed data. Thanks

Comment: The process will be the same just install elastic search on the other system & put the data folder in the node folder generally at location /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/ in ubuntu system and everything will work the same as it works in your system. you have to use the same index name and  same url as mentioned above . Hope this helps.

Comment: @AkashYadav I tried the same thing...see the edited section above. But it shows this exception .. search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed.. Any idea what is this about. Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if it's just querying in java here's an example :

```
MatchQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("user", "kimchy);
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch("twitter").setTypes("tweet");
srb.setQuery(qb);
SearchResponse response = srb.execute().actionGet();
//Here goes your code where you use response.getHits() that contains your items
```

Comment: Christophe, I want to ask, like if we have indexed the data and stored it in suppose XYZ/data folder, and I transfer that folder to some other computer, Then how can I use this data into new server and client.  Thanks

Comment: It's funny you ask, I did exactly this 2 days ago for a demo. Basically what I did is copy/paste the whole ElasticSearch server (with its data folder containing the data) and ran it on the new computer, worked like a charm (at least for demo purposes, I wouldn't suggest it for production, you never know). If you want to add the data into an already existing ElasticSearch server with other data, I don't think this will work, you'd probably need to find something else in the documentation.

Comment: Christophe I tried doing that, see the edit section of the question above..Do you know about this exception mentioned in question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The message you get by using my snippet usually indicates that your client doesn't manage to connect to your server. Check your server status (i.e. that you launched your server properly) and try using this.

```
    Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().client(true).node();
    client = node.client();
```

I don't think you need to specify the clustername unless you have some custom configuration i'm not aware of. Also check your index name.